# Apache Camel/ActiveMQ priority route

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have two AMQ queues that have the same consumers.
The first queue (Q1) handles 97% of the messages and the other (Q2) only 3%.
Problem is that messages in Q2 need to process messages as soon as they are queued.
So my problem is that when a message is available in Q2 I need somehow to suspend the first route to take it's consumers.
The apache camel routing looks like this:

```
<route id="q1">
    <from uri="jms:recordAnalysisRequests" />
    <to uri="bean:analysisService" />
</route>
<route id="q2">
    <from uri="jms:recordAnalysisRequestsFastTrack" />
    <to uri="bean:analysisService" />
</route>
```

What strategy should use?
I don't think I can use resequencer because Q1 could have thousands of messages queued up and I cannot fit all in a resequencer batch.
I was looking at the route throttling but I cannot figure out how to do it.
Also I was wondering if I can synchronize through a zookeeper node. Again I will need some guidance here if this solution is viable.

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[apache]` and `[camel]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[apache-camel]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 3):

You could place all messages in a single queue and use message priority http://activemq.apache.org/how-can-i-support-priority-queues.html

Second option, use a Camel Resequencer

```
<route id="q1">
    <from uri="jms:recordAnalysisRequests" />
    <setHeader headerName="CustomPriority">
       <constant>2</constant>       
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="direct:analysisDirect" />
</route>
<route id="q2">
    <from uri="jms:recordAnalysisRequestsFastTrack" />
    <setHeader headerName="CustomPriority">
       <constant>1</constant>       
    </setHeader>
    <to uri="direct:analysisDirect" />
</route>
<route id="q3">
    <from uri="direct:analysisDirect">
    <resequence>
        <header>CustomPriority</header>
        <to uri="bean:analysisService" />
    </resequence>
</route>
```

Third option (Camel 2.12), insteads of using a resequencer, use a SEDA endpoint with a PriorityBlockingQueue https://camel.apache.org/seda.html#SEDA-ChoosingBlockingQueueimplementation

Comment: I fall under the situation when I have slow consumers and I might have a lot of non priority messages in Q1: "Note, this sort of tradeoff can have significant performance implications, so you must test your scenarios thoroughly.". So the performance is my concern here.